# How to enable classpath scanning for @Entity classes in Spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

All my attempts at classpath scanning of @Entity classes failed in a Spring boot application. The most common solution I found on the web was this and it didn't work -

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
```

@EntityScan on a @Configuration class did not work either.

All the entities and their mappings were listed in orm.xml and I had to move back to using @Entity annotations.

One solution that got me half way there was -

```
<persistence-unit>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.acme.domain.Entity</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>
```

This way I could use the @Entity annotations if I listed entity classes in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I didn't find while searching, which is listed on [Spring Data JPA web page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html) is this -

```
ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor postProcessor = new ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor("com.acme.domain");
entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(postProcessor);
```

Now the classpath scanning of @Entity classes is enabled. No mappings in orm.xml and no listing of entities in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your code will help troubleshoot. Is there a github project you can share?

One thing to keep in mind is that SpringBoot takes an "opiniated" approach to everything. This means that for JPA, there is a "boot" way of doing things. Spring Tool Suite is your friend here.

Recommend checking this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) that shows you how to do JPA in Boot. Also, when using boot, I strongly recommend to start with a maven project setup from the [Spring Initializer](http://start.spring.io) project.